# Group By Summations in XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Say we have data like the following:

```
<ROW>
  <CAT_CODE>3 COE</CAT_CODE>
  <ACCT_2>4400</ACCT_2>
  <ACCT2_DESC>Employee Costs</ACCT2_DESC>
  <ACCT_3>4490</ACCT_3>
  <ACCT3_DESC>Salaries</ACCT3_DESC>
  <ACTUAL>55.30</ACTUAL>
</ROW>
```

And we are wanting to group everything by "ACCT_2" and CAT_CODE='3 COE' and created a table like the following:

```
+-----------------+----------+--------+
| Account Level 2 | Category | Actual |
+-----------------+----------+--------+
| 4400            | 3 COE    | 4,609  |
+-----------------+----------+--------+
| 4500            | 3 COE    | 9,870  |
+-----------------+----------+--------+
| 4600            | 3 COE    | 1,343  |
+-----------------+----------+--------+
 . . . 
+-----------------+----------+--------+
| Total:          |          | 23,998 |
+-----------------+----------+--------+
```

How could something like this be achieved? We have the following code:

```
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td>Account Level 2</td>
       <td>Category</td>
       <td>Actual</td>
     </tr>
     <xsl:for-each-group select="ROW[CAT_CODE='3 COE']" group-by="ACCT_3">
       <tr>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="ACCT_3"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="CAT_CODE"/></td>
         <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ACTUAL), '#,###')"/></td>
       </tr>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
     <tr>
       <td>Total: </td>
       <td></td>
       <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ROW[CAT_CODE='3 COE']/ACTUAL), '###,###')"/></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

But it looks like we are leaving some values out. We end up getting a correct Total line, but our rows above that do not sum to the total.

Note: Please forgive my ignorance as I'm very new to XML/XSL. I just started learning it today.

Comment: Showing us `for-each-group select="G_1[CAT_CODE='3 COE']"` while your input sample has no `G_1` elements doesn't allow us to tell where things go wrong. Consider to post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I meant to change that `G_1` to say `ROW`. My bad on that. I edited the question to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your summation expression should have been:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/ACTUAL), '#,###')"/>
```

in order to sum all members of the current group.  Your existing code was only summing the ACTUAL child elements of the context node - which for for-each-group is the first member of the group.